# How to clean a url with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with url when loading PHP scripts.

The problem is that at the time of making the request to a php script, it loads normally, but when requesting another script, in the url they begin to gather and it looks like this:

> **www.example.com/file.php/route1/file2.php**

I need this

> **www.example.com/file2.php**

when i request another file, I need to have this

> **www.example.com/file2.php**

What I need is to hide everything that it after **file1.php or file2.php** to load the other scripts without problems.

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your HTML content and .htaccess file it is hard to determine the exact cause of your issue(s).

Please verify the instructions in your .htaccess file. If you are using a Rewrite rule you need to validate that it is correct, for example:
`RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.in" [R=301,L]` If this rule is forcing a `/route` you obviously need to remove the `/route` from the instruction.

Please make sure to reference in your `<a>` tags the appropriate path. If you are not formatting it properly you will end up with concatenation. Are you using a framework? If so this may have an impact on your URL formatting.

Some example HTML a tags for you:
`<a href="http://example.com/file1.php">File 1</a>` and `<a href="/file1.php">File 1</a>` will perform the same provided you do not have other factors impeding this simple approach.